# Table Cell padding-bottom in CSS not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I have a table on my website where each table cell contains an image that is 138px X 138px. When I style `<td>` in CSS to have padding:0px; the table cell ends up with the size of 138px by 143px. I have not seen any reason as to why this is happening. Even when I do padding-bottom:-5px; the table remains at exactly the same size. What is happening!

The CSS:

```css
td
{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get that behavior in a jsfiddle?

Comment: What I do in times like this is add a `border` so I can see exactly where the element ends. Try adding `border:#333 3px solid;` to your `td` and see if you can troubleshoot.

Comment: Do you have margin in the `img` tag?

Comment: Post code of a table with the image in it as well.

Comment: Negative padding is invalid in CSS - can you please post an example?

Comment: I have actually never used jsfiddle before, il try it out:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you reset vertical-align to img tags ?

```css
td img {
    vertical-align:top; /* or bottom */ 
}
```

By defaut image stands on baseline wich explains that gap underneath.

Comment: It works! I've never understood the whole bassline principle, but il look into it - thanks alot!! :DD