# Why there is a gap between two vertical images?

Tags: css, image

I put two images together vertically but there is a gap, I try everything but I just can't find what is wrong?
On this website(left bottom yellow image),
http://www.jamesxu.com.au/contact

**HTML**

```
<div class="pic_wrap">  
    <img id="contact" src="http://www.jamesxu.com.au/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme-realone/images/contact_01.png"> 
    <a class="email" href="mailto:hi@jamesxu.com.au"> </a>
    <a class="message" href="http://www.jamesxu.com.au/contact/"> </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pic_wrap {width:216px; margin:auto;}
a.email {background:url(images/ico.png) left -80px no-repeat; display:inline-block; width:216px; height:35px; line-height:0; font-size:0;}
a.email:hover {background:url(images/ico.png) left -120px no-repeat ; }

a.message {background:url(images/ico.png) left -164px no-repeat; display:inline-block; width:216px; height:45px; line-height:0; font-size:0;}
a.message:hover {background:url(images/ico.png) left -208px no-repeat ;}
```

Comment: The site is inacessible, but try removing padding and border on both elements... (`padding: 0; border: 0;`)

Comment: You should always include the corresponding `html`code with the question, not just only link to your page. Otherwise if you fix your problem or your page goes away, your question would not be as helpful to other people then it could be.

Comment: Sorry, i try to extract HTML from my theme but doesn't work. So just put CSS here.

Comment: To Kroltan, The hosting from bluehost.com, don't know why can't access.

Answer (score 0):

That's because those 2 `A` tags (`.email` & `.message`) are `inline-block` and separated by a newline (Enter) character.

Change those 2 `A` elements to `display: block;` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `display: block;` to all elements inside `.pic_wrap`, currently your `a` tags are on `display: inline-block`

```
<div class="pic_wrap">  
  <img id="contact" src="http://www.jamesxu.com.au/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme-realone/images/contact_01.png"> 
  <a class="email" href="mailto:hi@jamesxu.com.au"> </a> //<--this needs to be display:block
  <a class="message" href="http://www.jamesxu.com.au/contact/"> </a> //<-- this needs to be display: block
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the display types to just `block`:

```
a.email {background:url(images/ico.png) left -80px no-repeat; display:block; width:216px; height:35px; line-height:0; font-size:0;}
a.message {background:url(images/ico.png) left -164px no-repeat; display:block; width:216px; height:45px; line-height:0; font-size:0;}
```

Tried and tested in Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Déja vue, a couple of days ago, image standing on baseline :)

is this the answer you are looking for [Table Cell padding-bottom in CSS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926066/table-cell-padding-bottom-in-css-not-working/16926245#16926245) (about image )

Answer (score 0):

in your a.email class, try "display: block;" instead of inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
a.email   { display: inline-block; }
a.message { display: inline-block; }
```

to

```
a.email   { display: block; }
a.message { display: block; }
```